# C# proxy with reporting services

Tags: c#, windows-authentication

I am trying to put together a simple C# proxy code to call a ssrs report.
Here is my C# code:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("reportProxy")]
    public IHttpActionResult get(string report)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Reportserver_SQL2014?/....");
        WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy();
        myproxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        request.Proxy = myproxy;
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        return Ok(response);

    }
```

I am calling my proxy method like this:

```
http://localhost/reportProxy?report=1234
```

I am getting 401 error that looks like this:

> { "Message": "An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage": "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.", "ExceptionType": "System.Net.WebException", "StackTrace": " at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()\r\n at PrismWeb.API.Controller.UtilityController.get(String report) in UtilityController.cs:line 248\r\n at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()" }

Can I just use Windows Authentication?

Thanks for the help.